# Give permission to hdf to remove directory

Tags: permissions, hadoop

When I run `hdf namenode -format` then it wants to remove a directory `/home/hadoop/hadooptmpdata/dfs/name/current` but it has no permission to do it.

How to give it a permission?

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo command `sudo hdf namenode -format`